# hover dropdown menu appears behind swf object on web page

Tags: css

I have an issue where the dropdown menu options appear beneath  the swfobject which has a list of videos. See here when you mouseover the dropdown menu options with submenus: http://newbie-cms.net/demo/

and I have the following code:

```
 <div name="player" id="player" style="width:auto;padding-left:200px;position:absolute;z-index:200">player</div>
</center>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var so = new SWFObject('mediaplayer1.swf', 'mpl', '818', '380', '8');
        so.addParam('allowscriptaccess',     'always');
        so.addParam('allowfullscreen',       'true');
        so.addParam('wmode',       'transparent');
        so.addVariable('file',               'playlist.xml');
        so.addVariable('width',              '818');
        so.addVariable('height',             '380');
        so.addVariable('displaywidth',       '550');
        so.addVariable('backcolor',          '0xFFFFFF');
        so.addVariable('frontcolor',         '0x5566FF');
        so.addVariable('bufferlength',       '5');
        so.addVariable('overstretch',        'fit');
        so.addVariable('autoscroll',         'true');
        so.addVariable('thumbsinplaylist',   'true');
        so.addVariable('autostart',          'true');
        so.addVariable('shuffle',          'false');
        so.addVariable('link','');
        so.addVariable('linkfromdisplay','true');
        so.addVariable('linktarget','_self');
        so.write('player');
  </script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject1.js"></script>
```

What am I missing in fixing this with the dropdown menu appearing behing the flash. How do I set the wmode=transparent with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `z-index: 999` to `.dropdown_5columns`. Works for me.

Comment: That was absolutely wonderful Sn0opy.Worked perfectly. My thanks indeed!

Comment: I would like toask another question on a jquery css conflict I have on the same page Sn0opy. I proceeded to add a jquery menu tab to the page and there is a clash in the css obviously as can be seen here again: http://newbie-cms.com/demo1/ .  I separated a page with only the jquery tabs here:http://newbie-cms.com/demo1/channeltabs/ and that works fine.   Also, the demo1/index.html page works fine without the tabs. But once i combine the tabs code with the videos page, the ul,li items of the tabs become displaced as can be seen : http://newbie-cms.com/demo1/

Comment: Please create a new question for that.